# Identifying unique texts

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula

I'm making a Utilization file for our team.

[image: Sample File]

I'm having a bit of difficulty in identifying what kind of workflow that the agent did that day.
I need to identify first the workflow done by that agent for a specific day because each workflow has a different AHT (average handling time) for the computation of their capacity for that day.

I have this file where

```
Column A = agent's name
Column B = date
Column C = workflow
```

is there a way to identify the workflows that the agent did that day?

note: there are agents that are working with different workflows each day.

Here's a sample of what I was trying to do.

[Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sDCi.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: I can't share the file due to system restrictions. but I have added the photo on the question.

Comment: The screenshot does not include the column letters, or row numbers, so it's tough to write you a formula.

Comment: sorry about that.

Column A = Month
Column B = Date
Column C = Name
Column D = Process
Column E = Productivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF((I2="")*(I3=""),,UNIQUE(IFERROR(FILTER(D2:D, B2:B=I2, C2:C=I3), "no data")))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hUHmQTGrKLWorjLFM2hBnaUMVcC-kPr5KqiJmuhIQp8/copy)